# add service reference to xamarin project

Tags: web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

How can I add "service reference" in Cross Platform (Xamarin Forms) e .NET Standard code strategy in vs2017? (image 1)

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E902H.png).

I can't add service reference to my project, I read many forum but in my .csproj I don't have target framework profile for edit it to 78. (image2)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQECo.png)

Answer (score 0):

The best idea here is to create a new portable class library, than select your platforms and add your services to it. Then you can add a link from your project to the class library you created (with the services inside).